# Find Cookie on PC

Tags: c#, http, fiddler

I am trying to understand how Cookies are found and transferred to the server.  Please see the output below from Fiddler:

[image]

How do I find this Cookie on my local PC.  I have got the Cookie path here:

[image]

How do I find the actual Cookie in this folder (Temporary Internet Files)? I am trying to understand what I should search for.

Comment: (IE only) Cookies are not stored in that folder, browse to shell:cookies for the real location.  The names are abstracted via a database, you can retrieve them (with some caveats) with the [WinInet API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385326(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Alex K, thanks.  How do I find the Cookie starting .ASPXFOR (see Fiddler screenshot in my OP) on my local PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox cookies are stored in your profile:

`%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`

as the file `cookies.sqlite` under one of the profiles.

More information:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

Chrome cookies are stored in

`%LocalAppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`

IE cookies are in `shell:cookies` and `shell:cookies/low`

Each browser has a different format for storing cookie data. IE cookie data is stored in randomized text files, and you should only access it using the  [approved methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9-0-2-update/), which are the InternetGetCookieEx and IEGetProtectedModeCookie APIs

Comment: Please see the cookie value in the HTTP Header of the Fiddler screenshot.  How would I find this Cookie on my local PC.  What is it - a Base64 string?

Comment: Expanded my answer. In short, they are stored in random filenames in a basically opaque format. Use the windows APIs to grab their contents.

Comment: thanks. How is the cookie encoded - is it base64? Is this a Cookie: .ASPXFOR..... (see the first screenshot in my OP).

Comment: Also there is a good chance that session cookies may not be persisted...

Comment: Cookies are basically just freeform key value pairs, so there's no standard for what's stored in that cookie. You'll need to look at what's generating that cookie and see how it processes it.